# Only dependancies are copied when deploying intellij plugins

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, kotlin

I am currently developing an intellij plugin using Kotlin and when i deploy it using the "prepare module XXX for deployment" only the dependencies are present in the .zip file and not the plugin itself. however it works fine when running/debugging it from the IDE.

Update: See you track [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157271)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Overriding project level output paths with module full paths (and not relative) solved the problem, and now the JAR is full again.Thanks, it drove me crazy :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround by manually copying the compilation output of the module except the META-INF into the generated zip file after doing this the plugin loads sucessfully